# how can i put file to a certain google drive account?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm using PHP to put some runtime created files on a specific Google Drive account.
If I'm logged on google with an account and I launch my script, these files will be uploaded on this account, even I use client ID and secret of a different account

Use case:
I'm logged with a@gmail.com, I use my script and files are sent to a@gmail.com's Google Drive instead of b@gmail.com's Google Drive

How can I upload these files to b@gmail.com account even if I'm logged with a@gmail.com account?

Thanks

The ex. code

```
    <?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$drive = new Google_Client();

$drive->setClientId(/*client id*/);
$drive->setClientSecret(/*client secret*/);
$drive->setRedirectUri(/*redirect uri (the same URI in the API configuration)*/); 
$drive->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$gdrive = new Google_DriveService($drive);

file_put_contents('token.json', $drive->authenticate());

$drive->setAccessToken(file_get_contents('token.json'));

$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My document');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType('text/plain');


$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
  'data' => 'example',
  'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
));


return true;
```

EDIT:

I use pathfinder solution and create a service account.
It seems working but I've still a problem: at the end of execution I can't find my file on gDrive...maybe I've done an invomplete configuration, even if I read the doc...

This is the code:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
$DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = '<email_in_api_access>@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'google-api-phpclient/<api_key_file>-privatekey.p12';

$key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
$auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
$key);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setUseObjects(true);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
$gdrive = new Google_DriveService($client);
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My document');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType('text/plain');
$createdFile = $gdrive->files->insert($file, array(
'data' => 'A test document',
'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
));
return true;
```

Comment: Have you tried something you want to share with us?

Comment: If you want to upload things to multiple accounts you might try a service account. It works well for google apps, but it may not work for what you want. You may need to put more info about what you are after: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation